# Can we set OR condition for fused location api - for either time interval or displacement

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

Can we get location (Fused Location API) based on either time interval or displacement, whatever happens first ?
Or only one condition can be applied at a time ?

Comment: based on time interval

Comment: Maybe it could work with a combination of [setMaxWaitTime()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#setMaxWaitTime(long)) and [setSmallestDisplacement()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#setSmallestDisplacement(float)), but I haven't tried.

Comment: No it just works either only for displacement or just for time intervals, not working for both